# When I use magento API(salesOrderShipmentCreate), item qty must be filled?

Tags: api, ce-1.9.0.1

I just want to change status of specific order to "shipped" by using ordernumber as key.

When I decided to use salesOrderShipmentCreate API, I found some logical problem.

```
$result = $proxy->salesOrderShipmentCreate($sessionId, '200000006', array('8', '1'), 'shipment comment');
```

In this code;  **array('8', '1')** should be the shippment qty of item. the item id('8') might be derived from earlier API-call-result (like salesOrderInfo).

Because of heavy loading in using API, I don't want to call extra API-call for just get id of items.
I don't ship products partially. **Always I ship entire order.**

Is there any good method to change status order to shipped with entire shipment qty without using item id?

Answer (score 2):

**ship products partially** 
Try This:

```
$itemQty = array();
foreach($order_product as $v){                    
    $itemQty[] = array(
        'order_item_id' => $v['op_ref_item_id'],
        'qty' => $v['op_quantity']
    );
}
$shipment_increment_id = $client->salesOrderShipmentCreate($sessionId,$order_increment_id, $itemQty,'My Shiped Comment');
```

**ship entire order**
Try This:

```
$itemQty = array();
$shipment_increment_id = $client->salesOrderShipmentCreate($sessionId,$order_increment_id, $itemQty,'My Shiped Comment');
```